# How to add SafetyNet attestation to Flutter application

Tags: flutter, safetynet, firebase-app-check

I was enabling AppCheck through SafetyNet in Google Play console for my Firebase-RT project (as recommended by the Google guys). I want now to configure a Flutter application to use it. How can I do that? I couldn't find any official way to do it.